# Probability that Markov chain state is not touched for at least n steps

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Consider a Markov chain with two states (1,2):

$$P={\begin{bmatrix}P_{11}&P_{12}\\P_{21}&P_{22}\end{bmatrix}}$$

I want the probability that after a state 1, state 1 is not touched for at least N consecutive steps (i.e. only state 2 is touched for at least N consecutive steps).

I think that the answer should be

$$ P_{12}(1-\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}P_{22}) $$

But I'm not sure if this is correct.

---

**EDIT** thanks a lot for the answers, I made a mistake in the question and I apologize, the answer that I meant was

$$ P_{12}(1-\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}P_{22}^k) $$

Is this still incorrect?

Comment: Your formula cannot be right, because for $N$ big enough you get a negative probability.

Answer (score 2):

You formula is not correct.

The answer should be $P_{12} P_{22}^{N-1}$, the first step is move from state 1 to state 2, then the chain has to stay in state 2 for the next $N-1$ steps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But in this way I don't see how the **at least N** is included. I made a mistake in my question, I actually meant
$$P_{12}(1-\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}P_{22}^k)$$

Because if $P_{22}^k$ is the probability to get 2 k times, then I think $(1-\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}P_{22}^k)$ should give the probability to get it **at least** N times. Is this still incorrect?

Comment: No, it isn't correct.  the *at least* $N$ times is there by demanding $X_2=X_3=X_4=\dots=X_{N+1}=(\text{state 2})$, which is basically what the $P_{22}^{N-1}$ is doing after conditioning on $X_2$ being state 2.

Answer (score 2):

This can be expressed as:
1. go from state 1 to 2, and stay there for at least N-1 units of time.
ie we have:
$p_{12}p_{22}^{N-1}$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But in this way I don't see how the **at least N** is included. I made a mistake in my question, I actually meant
$$P_{12}(1-\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}P_{22}^k)$$

Because if $P_{22}^k$ is the probability to get 2 k times, then I think $(1-\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}P_{22}^k)$ should give the probability to get it **at least** N times. Is this still incorrect?

Comment: Good spot. The way in which "at least N" is captured in the formula I provided is that you wish to have $p_{22}$ appearing $N-1$ times, and what comes afterwards is immaterial. (so in some sense you can think of it as multiplying by 1)